# VB.net Excel object writing to it

Tags: excel, vb.net, object

I am trying to write a simplified library for read&write to excel from a vb.net application.

I can only write to an excel file after using my CreatewWorkbook procedure. I cannot write to an excel file using my AccessXLFile procedure.

Can someone have a look?

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Imports Microsoft.Office

Public Class xlHandling

```
Private xlApp As New Excel.Application
Private xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
Private xlWorkBooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
Private xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

Private Sub releaseObject(ByVal obj As Object)                          'Closes an object using the garbage collector
    Try
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
        obj = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        obj = Nothing
    Finally
        GC.Collect()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function PathExists(ByVal sPath As String) As Boolean       'Validate path
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(sPath) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Function AccessXLFile(ByVal sFilePath As String) As Boolean 'Load an Excel file for reading & writing to it
    Dim bRet As Boolean = True
    Try
        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        xlWorkBooks = xlApp.Workbooks
        xlWorkBook = xlWorkBooks.Open(sFilePath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("File not found, or Excel installation fault.")
        bRet = False
          End Try
        Return bRet
End Function

Public Sub CloseXLFile()               'Clear memory
    Try
        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBooks)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlApp)
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function SheetExists(sName As String) As Boolean            'File Exists check
    Dim bResult As Boolean = False

    For i = 1 To xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count                        'Scan sheet name through workbook
        If xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Item(i).Name = sName Then
            bResult = True
        End If
    Next i
    Return bResult
End Function

Public Sub CreateWorkbook(ByVal sName As String, sPath As String, ByRef iDiag As Integer)
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.Application

    If xlApp Is Nothing Then                    'Error with excel installation on host PC
        iDiag = 1
    ElseIf (sName.Length = 0) Then              'Error with designed Workbook name
        iDiag = 2
    ElseIf (PathExists(sPath) = False) Then     'Error with pathname
        iDiag = 3
    Else
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        xlWorkSheet.Name = "Main"
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        If Not xlWorkSheet Is Nothing Then
            xlWorkSheet.Delete()
        End If
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(sPath + sName + ".xlsx")
    End If
    releaseObject(xlApp)
End Sub

Public Sub CreateWorksheet(sSheetName As String, ByRef iDiag As Integer)
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    If sSheetName.Length = 0 Then                                                     'Error sheet name null
        iDiag = 1
    ElseIf SheetExists(sSheetName)
        iDiag = 2
    Else
        Dim xlNewSheet = DirectCast(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Add(xlWorkBook.Worksheets(1), Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing), Excel.Worksheet)   'Create new sheet
        xlNewSheet.Name = sSheetName        'Rename new sheet
        MsgBox(xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What I meant was that I can't use the CreateWorksheet procedure after using the AccessXLFile function

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution why I could not make use of my CreateWorksheet procedure if I used AccessXLFile. I modified the following code:

`Public Sub CloseXLFile()               'Clear memory
        Try
            xlWorkBook.Save()
            xlWorkBook.Close()
            xlApp.Quit()
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
            releaseObject(xlWorkBooks)
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
            releaseObject(xlApp)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("?")
        End Try
    End Sub`

I added the xlWorkBook.Save()